# How to detect water level on an image?

Tags: c#, java, image, algorithm

My homework is to write a very simple application (Java or C#, I know both), which can detect water level of a glass of water / coke in a picture (it have to draw a line there). I don't even know how to start it. I have googled all day, but have found no useful results. Are there any good algorithms, which can detect the level of the liquid?

The photo is taken from the side, like this:

[image]

(it's also good if it detects both lines). So could you help me out with how to start? Use egde detection (are there any good basic algorythms?), or other method?

It would be best would be if it detected water, coke, and every liqued etc....

Comment: how are you planning on detecting it?  with a float, a scale, some optics?

Comment: *"very simple application"*  How do you have any idea of how hard or simple it will be until you have a working solution?  *"So could you help me out with how to start?"* Read your texts, consult your tutors, that is what they are there for.

Comment: A clean glas with water would be tough

Comment: Is this for an intro to computer graphics/computer vision course? What algorithms/techniques have you discussed so far?

Comment: Andrew Thomspon said it correctly.  if it's an assignment for a course, the TAs know what will make your professor happy, talk to them or your professor for help.  If you decide to do your own "functional" implementation, it still might not be what the prof wants.

Comment: How will you communicate the 'level of the liquid' to your instructor?

Comment: That is a horrible image to use for a 'simple' algorithm in edge detection. The picture is taken from an angle on a table with blue backlighting that floods everything out. The table edge creates a second, simulated water line. Try a better photo first.

Comment: With or without the meniscus? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to have to do some edge detection and then once you have the edges, try and find the level within the glass.  You could use a toolkit like [Aforge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html).  Then code to detect the edges is pretty simple, for example:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\water.jpg"));
// create filter
Edges filter = new Edges();
// apply the filter
filter.ApplyInPlace(b);

pictureBox1.Image = b;
```

Yields an image like this:

[image]

Now it should be a little bit easier to find the point of water in the glass.  Since all of the background noise has been eliminated, you can focus on determining which edge you should key off of.

Answer (score 0):

Check Hough transformation [here](http://shedletsky.com/hough/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to get the capacity of the glass in question.

Once you know how much water a glass can hold, you can draw two lines onto the image using functions that you write your self. I would advise one line for the glass size and one line for the water level super imposed over the image, you can then use these lines and the maximum capacity of the glass to form a correlation between the two and calculate the level of fluid contained within the glass.

Remember that your professors aren't interested so much in you getting the assignment 100% correct, they are more interested in preparing you to solve problems using your own initiative. Google searching can't always solve your problems.